# Некоторая проблема с чат ботом в вк на python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

Я не самый сведущий в делах программирования, так что прошу заранее меня простить если вопрос покажется глупым, а мои ответы на ваши решения ещё более глупыми, спасибо за понимание.
Проблема состоим в следующем: есть некоторый код, благодаря которому бот отсылает сообщение в ответ на любое другое сообщение в беседе. **Так вот, я бы хотел узнать каким образом я могу сделать так, чтобы бот отвечал не на все сообщения, а на определённые, заданные в коде?**
В VkLongPoll для этого есть событие text, в VkBotLongPoll я этой альтернативы не нашёл, увы.
Сам код:

````
from random import random
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType


vk_session = VkApi(token="токен бота")
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, "id группы бота")
vk = vk_session.get_api()

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat:


        random_id = round(random() * 10 ** 9)
        chat_id = int(event.chat_id)
        message = "ваше сообщение"


        vk.messages.send(
            random_id=random_id,
            chat_id=chat_id,
            message=message,
        )
    ```
````

Comment: Попробуйте: `print("Text: " + event.object.text)`

Comment: Простите, что я должен с этим сделать? Насколько я понимаю все сообщения отправляются ботом через `messages.send`.

Comment: Добавить в код и посмотреть в действии. Это должно выводить сообщения по типу MESSAGE_NEW, а дальше вы сможете сделаете так **чтобы бот отвечал не на все сообщения, а на определённые, заданные в коде**

Comment: Ноль реакции, как в консоли, так и в самих сообщениях,отсылаемых ботом. Так же попытался вставить `event.object.text` в условие отбора, в этом случае бот просто замолкает и совсем перестаёт отвечать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам. В условии отбора нужно было использовать `event.object.message['text'] == "нужное сообщение"`